# Heckman elasticities failed due to encountering discontinuous region with missing values - Stata

Tags: stata, heckman, elasticity

Please note first of all that this is a double-posting of a [question on statalist](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1323064-regions-with-missing-values-prevent-margins#post1323064) from the 17.1.2016 which as of now has not received any answer. I guess that its all right to double-post now because of what i read here (1).

I am Heckman-regressing the effect of wealth on charitable donations

```
heckman givings wealth, select(givings_dum = soc_eng_2011)
```

and would like to explore the effect further by calculating the elasticities using

```
margins, eyex(wealth)
```

. 
Which doesn't work out because Stata encounters the following error:

> could not calculate numerical derivatives -- discontinuous region with missing values encountered
>   r(459);

My first thought was that this really would be an issue with missings values but there are no missing values in *givings* if *givings_dum* is valid and vice versa (which would have surprised me, but better check):

```
misstable patterns givings givings_dum
```

Pattern

Frequency | **** 1 **** 2 ****

---

*** 13,407    |**** 1 **** 1 ****

---

******* 225 |**** 0 **** 0 ****

---

*** 13,632 |

Here(2) it is said that Stata checks via some kind of matrix if margins are estimable, which one gets via:

```
matrix H = get(H)
matrix list H
```

and looks like that:

[image: estimcheck matrix]

Which, referring to Jeff Pitblado (post (2)), should be fine.

So, i'm somewhat lost.

**Update 20.01.2016:**

Using the same data and the same heckman command

```
mfx, eyex varlist(wealth)
```

works.
But using the two-stage-modell with c.wealth included in the selection modell

```
heckman givings c.wealth, select(givings_dum = c.wealth soc_eng_2011) two
mfx, eyex varlist(wealth)
```

Returns the same error code r(459)

Running heckman without the two-stage specification runs Stata into backed up iterations (i break after 200 iteratio, from which roughly 170 are backed up).

```
heckman givings c.wealth, select(givings_dum = c.wealth soc_eng_2011) two
mfx, eyex varlist(wealth)
```

Also, not including negative values for wealth "solves" the problem, meaning that

```
heckman givings c.wealth if wealth > 0, select(givings_dum = soc_eng_2011)
margins, eyex(wealth)
```

works fine (dropping 2000 observations from originally 13100).

PS: Please note that model i posted is an oversimplification of the original model. I tried to scale the problem down two the most simple case (3).

Because i have not enough repuation i couldn't link the numbers, which instead i have done in the comments. I suppose the restriction is there for a reason but correct references seemed to me more important.

Comment: (1): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site
(2): http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-07/msg00514.html
(3): http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-12/msg00974.html

Comment: "Jeff" here is Jeff Pitblado, responsible for the posting cited as (2).

Comment: I'm sorry, i was under the impression that it is common to on Statalist to refer to one another with the first name. I edited that.

Comment: The small point is different, namely that most readers would have no idea who Jeff is unless they read your references. In general, never assume that people read your references! (This isn't Statalist, not that different advice applies.)